# Is there a WebView event for when rendering changes?

Tags: android, events, webview

Are there any method that gets called when there are render changes to the WebView?

I do know that "onPageFinished" gets called when a page loads, but what if there are changes when AJAX is used? any method that gets called in case if AJAX was used?

Comment: NIT: There are multiple questions / topics above. A WebView can change even without an AJAX call - or after the "page is finished". An AJAX (or other network call) does not indicate a WebView changes.

Comment: That's correct, the problem I'm stuck on, would be solved with getting the AJAX response body or with knowing WebView has changed and then checking for elements present on the WebView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you can use shouldInterceptRequest().
Check it out: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29